# Replace Single Word on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

The amount of buttons on my page are dynamically created, so adding an ID attribute to however many there are isn't ideal. I also of course do not want to add a class, as attaching the same class (buttons are generated in a PHP loop), will affect them all.

Here's what I mean.

All the buttons have the word `View` in them.

```
<button><span>View</span><br />One</button>
<button><span>View</span><br />Two</button>
<button><span>View</span><br />Three</button>
```

Using this jQuery function, I'm able to change the single word (and not the entire button text as my previous failed experiments have shown).

```
$("button").click(function() {
     $("button span").html($("button span").html() == 'View' ? 'Hide' : 'View');
});
```

But this script is changing the values for all the buttons with the word `View`.

How can I modify this (or use a different method), to only target the button clicked and not all buttons (as I said, preferably without adding ID attributes).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jpb1a674/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `this`. Inside the event, it refers to the element that raised the event.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var span = $(this).children().first();
  span.html(span.html() == 'View' ? 'Hide' : 'View');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button><span>View</span><br />One</button>
<button><span>View</span><br />Two</button>
<button><span>View</span><br />Three</button>
```

Comment: I've been trying this and it hasn't been working.  Well, it does work, but it also removes the words One Two and Three from the buttons... like in the edit you just provided.  I'm looking for a way to replace just the single in the buttom from `View` to `Hide` while preserving the other button text (which is why I added a `<span>`.. okay, your new edit worked haha.  Thank you!